Can I add a comma before a preposition just because I feel that the sentence needs a pause?
I know that we don't often add a comma before a preposition, but I HAVE seen commas coming before prepositions like "despite" and "before" from time to time. However, I'm not 100% sure that the sources where I've seen these instances are reliable; moreover, I have once been told by a native speaker that a comma before these two prepositions is unnecessary. Look at this example:

Mexico’s kiwi fruit exports started at 6 million New Zealand dollars in 2010, after which it experienced a significant decline to hit a trough of 2.4 million in 2011, before recovering to end the period at 3.3 million.

I think that the comma before the preposition here creates a nice pause because, without it, it seems that the second clause is a bit too long. Furthermore, the comma separates different trends in Mexico's kiwi fruit exports and makes the sentence more comprehensible. So, can I add a comma before a preposition just because I feel that the sentence needs a pause?
P.S. One more concern about this is consistency. If adding a comma before a preposition is a matter of style, do I have to consistently do that in one essay, or just do it wherever needed?

Side note:  what is the antecedent of "it" in your sentence?

@TimR Mexico's kiwi fruit exports. I used "it" because I thought "exports" here refer to the export value.

Would be better to use the singular "export" or the phrase "export revenue" or "they" in place of "it" if you use "exports".

Yes, it's usually fine to use a comma to mark a pause in a long sentence, for example where a speaker might pause for breath. Whether or not it's before a preposition makes no difference.
It follows from this that, because you happen to have put a comma before a preposition in one sentence, you do not have to put one before every preposition!
